# Getting Haskell to Distinguish Type Synonyms

Tags: haskell, types, type-alias, type-synonyms

I like the idea of Haskell type synonyms, because they allow for distinguishing between abstract datatypes that share underlying representations. Unfortunately, when I write a program like

```
data Vector a = Vec a a

-- Some definitions here about (+) and (*) for Vector ...

type Position = Vector Float
type Velocity = Vector Float
type Time = Float

step :: Position -> Velocity -> Time -> Position
step p v dt = p + v*dt

p :: Position
p = Vec 0.0 0.0

v :: Velocity
v = Vec 1.0 1.0

p' = step v p 0.01
```

This is perfectly valid Haskell code, despite `v` and `p` being in the wrong spots. I would like to strengthen the distinction between type synonyms, such that they still share underlying representation, but are not accepted as each other in function application. Is this possible?

Comment: You should use `newtype` instead lf `type`.

Comment: @Shersh To answer a question, use the Post Your Answer button, Comments are for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements to the question.

Comment: But it's impossible to get achievement for many comments with `5+` upvotes otherwise... StackOverflow policy encourages me to write such comments instead of answers!

Comment: @Shersh That's no excuse. Part of the challenge is writing *appropriate* comments that get up-voted.

Comment: @amalloy, sometimes one can write a comment (like Shersh's) in a few seconds and help the OP out. But one may not be able to write a proper answer in that time. The above comment would likely not be well received if it posed as an answer.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, I'm aware that's the idea, but I don't think that's something to encourage. Something that can easily be answered in a seven-word comment will quickly have a real Answer, too - in this case, a thorough answer came in just two minutes after the comment "answer". I would rather we get a real Answer, and the presence of a comment like this discourages posting an Answer, because "OP's already been helped".

Comment: From https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype:

"Data can only be replaced with newtype if the type has exactly one constructor with exactly one field inside it." I suppose I could just do ```newtype Vector a = Vector (a, a)``` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make `Vector` a [phantom type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type) as follows:

```hs
data Vector t a = Vec a a

data Pos
data Vel

type Position = Vector Pos Float
type Velocity = Vector Vel Float
```

Now, you can define instances of `Position` and `Velocity` like you'd normally do:

```hs
p :: Position
p = Vec 0.0 0.0

v :: Velocity
v = Vec 1.0 1.0
```

However, it won't allow you to use them interchangeably:

```hs
type Time = Float

step :: Position -> Velocity -> Time -> Position
step p v dt = p + v*dt -- you might have to change this definition

p' = step v p 0.01 -- won't compile
```

You can also make things more precise by using `DataKinds` and `KindSignatures`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data VectorType = Pos | Vel

data Vector (t :: VectorType) a = Vec a a

type Position = Vector Pos Float
type Velocity = Vector Vel Float
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think it's more common these days to say that a type constructor has one or more phantom parameters than to say it's a phantom type.

Comment: I believe I saw a similar solution for C++. Unfortunately not as elegant as I was hoping (especially since it can't be applied to datatypes that are defined in imported libraries), but useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

`newtype` is likely what you want, or at any rate, the best we've got.  Like `type`, it defines a new name for an existing type, and the runtime representation will be the same.  Unlike `type` (but like `data`), they are considered different during type checking, and there is a new data constructor.

So you might have code like:

```
newtype Position = Position (Vector Float)
p :: Position
p = Position (Vec 0 0)
```